# 2 comboBoxes with DatasSource from Dictionary<string>, List<string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox

I have 2 commboBoxes with the following code:

```
  Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            { "A", new List<string> { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5" }},
            { "B", new List<string> { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5" }},
            { "C", new List<string> { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5" }},
        };

        comboBox1.DataSource = dict.ToList();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
```

Is it possible to display the values ("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5") to comboBox2 when I select "A" from comboBox1 ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to be done. It's prolly already been answered. Bt we won't be needing that much. Here is the code :

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict;       
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            { "A", new List<string> { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5" }},
            { "B", new List<string> { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5" }},
            { "C", new List<string> { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5" }},
        };
        cb1.DisplayMember = "Key";
        cb1.DataSource = dict.ToList();

    }

    private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                      
            cb2.DataSource = dict[cb1.Text];              
    }
```

The modification is correct : 
set DisplayMember First, and then the data source.